# Is there a XOOPS way to list contents of a DB table?

Tags: content-management-system

I am working in a new Audio Management Module for XOOPS.
I am done with adding, deleting, editing categories and now I am working with listing the list of categories (admin side). I checked some other modules and found they used something called CriteriaCompo.

What is this? Is it a XOOPS way to list DB tables?

If yes, How does it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It deals with query clause, check class/criteria.php for details.